# How to fill a "ViewModel" for dynamic filter which need to get children of different entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC 2.*, and using McirosoftEntityFrameworkCore.
I have **following tables with relation in parentheses**:

```
Categories(1<==>*)CategoryProduct(*<==>1)Products(1<==>*)AttributeProduct(*<==>1)Attributes(*<==>1)AttributeCategories
```

I want to create a dynamic filter box in my app which my **ViewModel** for filter box is as following:

```
 Category(Children==>)AttributeCategories(Children==>)Attributes(Children==>)ProductAttributeValues
```

> I'm using [Entity Attribute Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) for my "ProductAttribute" table.

The queries which I've tried are as follow:

Using LINQ:

```
var linqQuery = from c in _context.Categories
                join cp in _context.CategroyProducts on c.Id equals cp.CategoryId
                join p in _context.Products on cp.ProductId equals p.Id
                join pa in _context.ProductAttributes on p.Id equals pa.ProductId
                join a in _context.Attributes on pa.AttributeId equals a.Id
                join ac in _context.AttributeCategories on a.AttributeCategoryId equals ac.Id
                where c.Id == categoryId
```

> This query need to use multiple group by which is challenging for me.

Using Include and foreach:

```
 var includeQuery= _context.Categories
            .Include(x => x.CategroyProducts)//step1
            .ThenInclude(x => x.Product)//step2
            .ThenInclude(x => x.ProductAttributes)//step3
            .ThenInclude(x => x.Attribute)//step4
            .ThenInclude(x => x.AttributeCategory);//step5
```

> The challenge in this query is to going from step1==>step5==>step4==>step3, which I can't achieve that in foreach.

What is the best way to fill the ViewModel?

Comment: The for loops have to be step1, step2, step3, step4, then step5.  You add a new row of the View in step 5.  Then put into the row data in any order using the index item from each of the for loops.  So if the for loops indexes are a,b,c,d,e then a row would be a.Name, e.quantity, d.color, b.price, c.value